# Add an controller to application.html.erb layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to build an app which handles multiple pages, and the user can add to the app (from a form) a page, then add the added page to a pages table. (Normally)

All of this I know how to do and I don't have any issues at it.

The problem is that I want to create a menu in application.html.erb, but I need to get the pages table data from a controller, so I tried to pass regular instance variables from application_controller.rb to application.html.erb, and it didn't work.

In application_controller.rb:

```
    @foo = "bar"
```

In application.html.erb:

```
   <%= @foo %>
```

**I don't even get an error, there is just nothing in the view. (I mean the variable isn't there, I can still see other content)**

How can I attach a controller for application.html.erb? (Or pass variables to application.html.erb) **Thanks for any help.**

**SOLUTION:** In you application_controller you can do

```
    before_action :set_page


    def set_page
      @foo = "bar"
    end
```

This will run the set_page action before every action in your application which should accomplish what you want.

Thanks to [ruby_newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597730/ruby-newbie)!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you application_controller you can do

```
before_action :set_page


def set_page
  @foo = "bar"
end
```

This will run the set_page action before every action in your application which should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks! It is working! +1 and I'll mark your answer as the solution in 9 mins... :D